# Shake Text Input if Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this Javascript and HTML code:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    function validate(e) {
        var username = document.getElementById('username');
        if (username.value.trim() == '') {
            username.style.backgroundColor = '#ff4c4c';
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            username.style.backgroundColor = null;
        }
        var password = document.getElementById('password');
        if (password.value.trim() == '') {
            password.style.backgroundColor = '#ff4c4c';
            e.preventDefault();
        }else {
            password.style.backgroundColor = null;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('submit', validate);
}
</script>

<div id="navrow">
    <img style="float: left;" src="questerslogoresized.png" />
    <ul>
        <li>Register</li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</li>
        <li>About</li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</li>
        <li>Reviews</li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</li>
        <form id='login'  action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post'>
            <div style="position: absolute; right: 120px;">
                <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
                <input type='text' name='username' class="formlogin" placeholder='Username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="20" />
                <span id='login_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                <input type='password' class="formlogin" placeholder="Password" name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
                <span id='login_password_errorloc' class='error'></span>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
            <!--<div class='short_explanation'><a href='reset-pwd-req.php'>Forgot Password?</a></div>-->
            <div><span style='color: #fff; position: absolute; top: 55px; right: 398px;'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</ul>
```

Currently if the text box input is empty, the colour of it changes to red. I'm looking for how to also make an **empty box shake**.

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function () {

    function validate(e) {
        var username = document.getElementById('username');
        if (username.value.trim() == '') {
            username.style.backgroundColor = '#ff4c4c';

            // Add a class that defines an animation
            username.classList.add('error');
          
            // remove the class after the animation completes
            setTimeout(function() {
                username.classList.remove('error');
            }, 300);
          
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            username.style.backgroundColor = null;
        }
        var password = document.getElementById('password');
        if (password.value.trim() == '') {
            password.style.backgroundColor = '#ff4c4c';
            
            // Add a class that defines an animation
            password.classList.add('error');
          
            // remove the class after the animation completes
            setTimeout(function() {
                password.classList.remove('error');
            }, 300);
          
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            password.style.backgroundColor = null;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('submit', validate);
}
```

```css
.error {
    position: relative;
    animation: shake .1s linear;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

@keyframes shake {
    0% { left: -5px; }
    100% { right: -5px; }
}
```

```html
<form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post'>

<input type='text' name='username' class="formlogin" placeholder='Username' id='username' maxlength="20" />
<input type='password' class="formlogin" placeholder="Password" name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery `shake` effect for that.

First, make sure you **link the latest jquery js file** to your webpage followed by the **jquery-ui file** after like this:

```
<script src="path-to-your-jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

then,

Just wrap your input box in a div like this:

```
<div class="shakeInput">
  input type='text' name='username' class="formlogin" placeholder='Username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="20" />
</div>
```

And then use jquery like this:

```
$( ".shakeInput" ).effect( "shake" );
```

You will have to add proper `if statements` for the shake just like you did with the red background-color above.

Answer (score 0):

There is decent a cross-browser library of CSS animations https://github.com/daneden/animate.css[css animation by daneden](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css). Also, use jquery which makes life easier.